# In a generalized additive model (GAM), how to relate statistical significance at the model level to spline confidence intervals?

Tags: statistical-significance, confidence-interval, generalized-additive-model

I am running a GAM in pyGAM with a spline and a factor term. The summary reports the spline term as highly significant, along with several warnings:

```
Feature Function                  Lambda               Rank         EDoF         P > x        Sig. Code   
================================= ==================== ============ ============ ============ ============
s(0)                              [0.6]                6            2.7          6.34e-06     ***         
f(1)                              [0.6]                2            1.0          7.06e-01                 
intercept                                              1            0.0          0.00e+00     ***         
==========================================================================================================
Significance codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
WARNING: Fitting splines and a linear function to a feature introduces a model identifiability problem
     which can cause p-values to appear significant when they are not.
WARNING: p-values calculated in this manner behave correctly for un-penalized models or models with
     known smoothing parameters, but when smoothing parameters have been estimated, the p-values
     are typically lower than they should be, meaning that the tests reject the null too readily.
```

Using the plotting routine suggested by PyGAM I can visualize the spline-estimated function along with 95% confidence intervals:

[image: spline term approximation]

My question is how to relate these two sources of information, if they can be related.

One particular question is whether the confidence intervals can be interpreted the way CIs are often interpreted in, say, an OLS linear regression: that is, the predictor is considered "significant" when both CIs are on the same side of zero. By that rationale the impact of this variable is only "significant" at lower values of `s(0)` when the upper CI is less than zero along with the lower CI. The fact that the CIs expand in their range in regions of the variable that have few samples would seem to support this interpretation. Is this a reasonable interpretation of these CIs?

Does this interpretation relate to the significance code reported in the summary in a straightforward way, for example, does the fact that *part* of the spline impacts the log-odds negatively with over 95% confidence causes the variable to be considered significant in the summary?